# Pandas Sort Order of Columns by Row

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['1','2','3','7'],
                   'B' : [7,6,5,4],
                   'C' : [5,6,7,1],
                   'D' : [1,9,9,8]})
df=df.set_index('A')
df

    B   C   D
A           
1   7   5   1
2   6   6   9
3   5   7   9
7   4   1   8
```

I want to sort the order of the columns descendingly on the bottom row like this:

```
    D   B   C
A           
1   1   7   5
2   9   6   6
3   9   5   7
7   8   4   1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to take the transpose, then `sort_values`, then transpose back.

```
df.T.sort_values('7', ascending=False).T
```

or

```
df.T.sort_values(df.index[-1], ascending=False).T
```

Gives:

```
   D  B  C
A         
1  1  7  5
2  9  6  6
3  9  5  7
7  8  4  1
```

Testing

my solution

```
%%timeit
df.T.sort_values(df.index[-1], ascending=False).T

1000 loops, best of 3: 444 µs per loop
```

alternative solution

```
%%timeit
df[[c for c in sorted(list(df.columns), key=df.iloc[-1].get, reverse=True)]]

1000 loops, best of 3: 525 µs per loop
```

Comment: Can I do it without referencing the value '7' explicitly?

Comment: Will it always be the last row?

Comment: Yes, it will always be.

Comment: Nice solution, but may be inefficient for large dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sort_values (by the index position of your row) with axis=1:

```
df.sort_values(by=df.index[-1],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation that does not involve transposition:

```
df = df[[c for c in sorted(list(df.columns), key=df.iloc[-1].get, reverse=True)]]
```